# paramiko/ Socket closes after returning console object from function

Tags: python, sockets, paramiko

I try to return socket object from function, but  after `return` socket immediatly closes. Any help is greatly appreciated :) Thanks

```
def get_connection(ip, log, paswd):
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(ip, username=log, password=paswd, timeout=100)
    console = ssh.invoke_shell()
    print(console)
    return console


def get_version(console, host):
    promt = console.recv(1000)
    if '>' in str(promt):
        console.send('enable\n')
        console.send('P@ssw0rd\n')
    console.send('terminal length 0\n')
    console.send('show version\n')
    time.sleep(2)
    out = console.recv(5000).decode('utf-8')
    system_version_finder = re.search('#show version\r\n(.+)', out)
    if system_version_finder:
        system_version = system_version_finder.group(1)
    else:
        system_version = 'Unknown'
    print(host + '\s' + system_version)


def upload_config(console, file_path):
    console.send('configure terminal\n')
    with open(file_path, 'r') as config_file:
        for line in config_file:
            console.send(line)

for host in options.ip_address_list:
    console = get_connection(host, options.login, options.password)
    print(console)
    get_version(console, host)
    if options.conf_file_path:
        upload_config(console, options.conf_file_path)
```

This is output of script:

```
<paramiko.Channel 0 (open) window=1024 -> <paramiko.Transport at 0x34f5e10 (cipher aes128-cbc, 128 bits) (active; 1 open channel(s))>>
<paramiko.Channel 0 (closed) -> <paramiko.Transport at 0x34f5e10 (unconnected)>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "llearn.py", line 65, in <module>
    get_version(console, host)
  File "llearn.py", line 32, in get_version
    console.send('terminal length 0\n')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\paramiko-1.16.0-py3.4.egg\paramiko\channel.py", line 698, in send
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\lib\site-packages\paramiko-1.16.0-py3.4.egg\paramiko\channel.py", line 1058, in _send
OSError: Socket is closed
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hmm, I think the contents of `ssh` in `get_connection` might be garbage collected after the function returns, because paramiko isn't holding on to it in `console`.

Try:

```
def get_connection(ip, log, paswd):
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(ip, username=log, password=paswd, timeout=100)
    console = ssh.invoke_shell()
    console.keep_this = ssh
    print(console)
    return console
```

Note we're now storing a reference to `ssh` on `console`.

On FreeBSD, your version doesn't produce errors, but it doesn't seem to work either. Adding that line makes it work for me.